# C++ Segmentation fault with same array index

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have the following piece of code:

```
bool *pho=new bool[n];
memset(pho, 0, sizeof(bool) * n);

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int d=2;

    cout << "i=" << i << ", d="<<d<< endl;

    pho[d] = true;
}
```

Running with input `n=8` results in the following output:

```
i=0, d=2
i=1, d=2
[Segfault]
```

I don't understand why this is happening! Setting the same location in the array results in a segfault for some reason. I have run the program several times and it always produces the same output.

Stepping through the code with a debugger, I can see that the value of d (the index) is 2 when the array gets accessed.

I have tried using global arrays and also static global arrays, both of which result in the same error.

Is there something wrong with my IDE and compiler? I am using MinGW with Eclipse CDT, running with std/c++11 option enabled.

Here is the whole source file, in case any other part of the program is causing problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

vector<unordered_set<int>> adj;

static bool *visited;

pair<int, int> dfs(int node) {
    if (visited[node])
        return make_pair(0, node);
    pair<int, int> best = make_pair(0, node);
    for (int neigh : adj[node]) {
        pair<int, int> alt = dfs(node);
        alt.second++;
        best = max(best, alt);
    }
    return best;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n, m, def;
    cin >> n ;

    cin >> m;

    bool *pho=new bool[n];
    memset(pho, 0, sizeof(bool) * n);


    int *degrees=new int[n];
    memset(degrees, 0, sizeof(int) * n);

    cout << "n="<<n<<", m="<<m<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int d=2;

        cout << "i=" << i << ", d="<<d<< endl;

        pho[d] = true;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        adj[a].insert(b);
        adj[b].insert(a);
        degrees[a]++;
        degrees[b]++;
    }

    queue<int> next;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (degrees[i] == 0) {
            next.push(i);
        }
    }

    while (!next.empty()) {
        int node = next.front();
        next.pop();
        if (pho[node])
            continue;
        for (int neigh : adj[node]) {
            adj[node].erase(neigh);
            adj[neigh].erase(node);
            degrees[node]--;
            degrees[neigh]--;
            if (degrees[neigh] == 1)
                next.push(neigh);
        }
    }

    visited=new bool[n];
    memset(visited, 0, sizeof(bool) * n);

    pair<int, int> pivot = dfs(def);

    memset(visited, 0, sizeof(bool) * n);
    pair<int, int> end = dfs(pivot.second);

    int dist = end.first; //number of edges she only has to walk once

    int tree = n - 1; //number of edges in tree

    int otherdist = tree - dist; //number of edges she has to walk twice

    int total = dist + otherdist * 2;

    cout << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I have done that! And I can see that `d=2` when the array is accessed.

Comment: @AJC: There's something else going on. You most likely invoked undefined behavior in some other part of your program.

Comment: @KemyLand Alright, I will include the whole source file. But nothing seems wrong to me...

Comment: @AJC You use `std::vector`, but then you don't use it.  Why not `std::vector<int> degrees(n)` instead of `new[]`?  Second, if `n <= 2`, you are accessing memory out-of-bounds with `d = 2`.  You should hard-code the values you're using instead of `cin`.  Regardless of all of that, assume you get passed that error -- you run right into the next one with the `for` loop accessing an empty vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are wrong :

```
adj[a].insert(b);
adj[b].insert(a);
```

You need to create `unordered_map` instance with `a` and `b` as keys, then respectively insert `b` and `a` as value. You don't need to have a vector of sets if you need key-value pairs.

Comment: But that defeats the purpose of the data structure... I need to be able to access the list of "b" that is connected to each "a". Anyways, could you explain a bit more on why it is wrong? The code seems to work when I remove any use of the vectors...

Comment: It's wrong 'cause you don't allocate memory to your vector and then try to access `adj[a]`, whereas no memory has been allocated to hold something for index `a`. If you want to continue this way, then first allocate memory to your vector, and then insert the elements. @AJC

Comment: I thought the c++ vector automatically allocates. Or do I need to use the insert function?

Comment: Yes, only when you push, not try to access. You can just allocate the memory first, and then continue inserting the vertices. @AJC

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time! I'm just getting confused by which types need allocation and which types are statically allocated

Comment: @AJC Using `adj.at(a).insert(b);` would have alerted you to the problem.  An `out_of_range` exception would have been thrown.